# Excluding static JS files for compilation with Babel + webpack

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, bundle, openlayers-3, babeljs

I use **webpack** and **Babel** in my new project. Everything works great until adding static JS files. Normally bundling operation takes 5 seconds. But after adding [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) library bundling takes about 420 seconds!!! OpenLayers JS file size about 490 KB and it is uglified. So it doesnt need compilation.

I tested without using **Babel** just with **webpack**, it took 5 seconds. So the problem is about Babel compilation. How can i prevent Babel not compile OpenLayers and just add it to result bundle file. Also I can use other external JS files as well as OpenLayers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude it:

```
{
  // ...
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/ // exclude all package you install
}
```

You can read more about this in https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-exclude